# Make a flutter custom transition like page view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to make a custom transition like `PageView` in flutter when navigate to another page like image below but I do not know how. I used `SlideTransitiondid` but it does not give me the desired result

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SlideTransitions extends CustomTransition {
  @override
  Widget buildTransition(
      BuildContext context,
      Curve curve,
      Alignment alignment,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: Tween(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
            .animate(animation),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[pageview transition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNMQZ.gif)

Comment: The transition of PageView is determined by the velocity of the swipe. So every transition from PageView is every so slightly different (shorter/longer) than one another. To get something similar you can give your animation a curve, or go more low level and create your own route.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition) `PageTransitionType.rightToLeft` . It's kinda similar to pageview swipe